# Kali installation stuck at Install the GRUB boot loader

Tags: linux, debian, grub, kali-linux, disk-encryption

I am doing encrypted disk installation. First partition is /dev/sda1, mount point is /boot and it is unencrypted and second partition /dev/sda2, mount point / and it is encrypted partition. Whole installation went fine but stuck at Install the GRUB boot loader on a hard disk. It's not going anywhere from here. No movement in progress bar.

See image:

[image]

Update:

I have just tried to install without any disk encryption and it is stucked again on same step.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the installation without an internet connection. 
You can skip some steps that require internet by hitting the `esc` key and manually select the next step.

When everything is installed you only need to set the repository URL in the `sources.list` manually.

```
cd /etc/apt/source.list
gedit sources.list
```

add the line at the top:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

and run the `apt-get update`, you know how it works.

Comment: How I will boot into installed Kali without GRUB? Did you read the question?

Comment: So you are saying that the failed installation is not the problem? And that the actual problem is that you don't want to install grub at all? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I hadthe same trouble while doing an install without internet.
That was solved by re-running the GRUB install step:

1. press ctrl+alt+F2 or etc to switch to another blank terminal session, while in the stuck screen.
2. kill some of the process later than update-grub, such as the osprob etc.
3. switch back to graphical install, by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F5 on my pc, you found that the GRUB install failed and can go back.
4. do install the grub again, that I successfully finished the step.